# Invoke-Command executes on remote machine without having an effect

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I'm trying to run a command on a VM using Invoke-Command. The command should stop a program that processes jobs after it finishes its current job. It works if I run it in the terminal using RDC.

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Vault Client 2021\Explorer\JobProcessor.exe' /stop
```

But if I run it from a different machine using Invoke-Command nothing seems to happen.

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName 'hostname' -Credential (Get-Credential)
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    & 'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Vault Client 2021\Explorer\JobProcessor.exe' /stop
}
```

However [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) shows the command come in for both cases, but the program is still running.

I have also tried using Start-Process with the same result, i.e. it works in the terminal on the VM but not using Invoke-Command.

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Vault Client 2021\Explorer\JobProcessor.exe' -ArgumentList '/stop'
```

I've been stuck for many days and I've exhausted my googlable knowledge for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that file exists on the remote computer?

For simplicity, I rewrote your command to a known executable that is always there in Windows and returns unique info for any given computer.

```
C:\> & 'C:\Windows\system32\HOSTNAME.EXE'
server1
C:\> icm {& 'C:\Windows\system32\HOSTNAME.EXE'}
server1
C:\> icm {& 'C:\Windows\system32\HOSTNAME.EXE'} -ComputerName server2
server2
```

Here's your script with some error handling.

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName 'hostname' -Credential (Get-Credential)
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    $exe = 'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Vault Client 2021\Explorer\JobProcessor.exe'
    $ok = Test-Path $exe
    if ($ok) {& $exe /stop} else {
        Write-Warning "EXE not present on $($env:COMPUTERNAME)!"
    }
}
```

Learn how to add error handling and you'll be well on your way to solving your problems faster and getting more stuff done.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. It wouldn't work when I run the command locally on the machine if it didn't exist. It also looks like the command is coming through but somehow not doing anything (Process Monitor).

Comment: I don't know what your command does. If it doesn't produce any output, you'll have to script out a test of some type and include it in your scriptblock.